# If $A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ are both nonsingular real matrices, where $n$ is odd, show that $AB + BA \neq0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been puzzling over this for a while now. I tried to find something in the properties of nonsingular matrices as well as the properties of determinants that might relate, but so far I've found nothing that seems relevant, so maybe I'm really far off.

I'm thinking that eventually it will be a proof by contradiction by saying that $n$ is odd and then setting the above equation equal to $0$ to show it can't work, but I don't even know where to start in order to get to that point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose not, so that one can choose $A, B$ s.t. $AB = -BA$. What is the determinant of each side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$
AB = -BA \implies \det(AB) = (-1)^n \det (BA)
$$

Comment: Where does the $(-1)^n det(BA)$ come from? Is this a property of determinants?

Comment: @user2113035 this is  the multilinearity. Use linearity with respect to the $n$ columns.